# Intellij split or move the declaration to the main class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

How i can split or pull up the variables?

I have this bunch of code:

```
public class GeometryDisplayAngles {
public static double angleCy;

public static void getAngles() {
    public static double angleAx = scanner.nextDouble();
    angleCy = scanner.nextDouble();
   }
}
```

What is the shortcut to push up the `angleAx` like `angleCy`?

In my case i should use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> like reminded [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/refactoring-2.html). but it's give me :

[image]

Comment: So your question is how could you access the one variable from one class to another class is it ?

Comment: @Lokesh I think that's fine because i start to search with that title i wrote in question.

Comment: Do you mean "Refactoring - Extract Field"? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/refactoring-2.html

Comment: @android I didn't get you

Comment: @Pang  i reached this site many times, but which one should i use ? i tried them all.

Comment: Are you trying to turn `angleAx` (a local variable) into like `angleCy` (a field / a member variable)?

Comment: @Pang yes i think that.!

Comment: Put the caret on `angleAx`, then press the shortcut key for "Refactoring - Extract Field".

Comment: @Pang that's not working indeed.

Comment: What platform are you on? Please choose the correct platform in the dropdown on the top right of https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/refactoring-2.html Also, make sure you're viewing the help page of the correct IntelliJ version, such as https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/14.0/refactoring-2.html

Comment: @Pang check edit.

Comment: *"Selected block should represent an expression"* What block did you select? Please **[edit]** and update your question to show us enough information for us to help you.

Comment: @Pang the `variable` is inside `getAngles()` and i need to move it into the main class `GeometryDisplayAngles` no thing to edit indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the cursor on angleAx and press ctrl-alt-F or right click and select refactor->extract->field. You will then end up with code as below, which is I think what you are after:

```
public static double angleCy;
private static double angleAx;

public static void getAngles() {
    angleAx = scanner.nextDouble();
    angleCy = scanner.nextDouble();
}
```